# AND between multiple form clauses

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I have this viewModel

```
var viewModel = from c in _context.Companies
                join co in _context.Component on c.id equals co.company_id 
                select new Joincco { Companies = c, Component = co}  ;
```

and another model:

```
from check in _context.Companies 
where 
    check.company_type.Contains(checkedBoxes[.....]) || 
    check.company_type.Contains(....) || 
    check.company_type.Contains(....) 
select new Joincco { Companies = check }
```

I need a new view that can provide AND between them.
I need to get `company_type`s from Companies that contains specific values and some properties equals a specific value from component.How can I do that?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by *"AND"*?  There's more than one way to interpret that. "Union" is everything from the first *and* everything from the second. "Intersect[ion]" is everything that's in both the first *and* the second. See how that can be confusing? Which term describes what you want? By the way, LINQ has methods both `Union` and `Intersect` methods!

Comment: as I said a condition for Companies and a condition for component must be met but  Union might work, I'll try @madreflection

Comment: thanks intersect works @madreflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `intersect`

```
return View(deneme.Intersect(longlinq).OrderBy(m => m.Companies.company_name));
```